# Finding index number of dictionary item in a list based on a given value

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, class, dictionary

I'm trying to access the index number of a dictionary that is stored within a list. I'm trying to print out a statement based on this index but I'm unsure of how to go about it.

Here's my current code:

```
def getSpecies(self, animalName):
        for items in self.animalList:
            for key, value in items.items():
                if self.animalName == value:
                    type = self.animalList[itemsIndex]['Type']
                    print (str(self.animalName) + "' is a " + type)
```

Where `self.animalName` is a user input and `self.animalList` contains the list of dictionaries.

I want the example output to be:

```
Shamu is a Whale
```

An example of how the list looks like is this:

```
self.animalList = [{'Litter': '3', 'Type': 'Whale', 'Mass': '300', 'Name': 'Shamu'}, 
                   {'Litter': '0', 'Type': 'Bird', 'Mass': '5', 'Name': 'Woody'}]
```

Comment: Where does the index number come into this?

Comment: I think the best way to say it is that, I would be prompting the user for a name of an animal that is stored within the list, then I would attempt to take the name of the animal and compare it to the values within the dictionaries. If the name matches, obtain the index number..but I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: I would imagine your second for loop isn't necessary either. You only need to find the value for `'Name'` key. I'd also avoid using `type` for a variable name since it's a built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) like:

```
for itemsIndex, items in enumerate(self.animalList):
```